# Non singularity

Tags: linear-algebra

If the classical adjoint of a matrix $A$ is non singular, how to show that $A$ is also non singular.?

Comment: That expression can only be used provided that A is nonsingular.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. ${{{{{}}}}}$

Comment: Its okay.......

Comment: I've worked it out. Welcome to check my answer.

Comment: $\det(adj A)=det(A)^{n-1}$. So the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 5):

If a classical adjoint of $A$ means the transpose of cofactor matrix of $A$, then observe the identity
$$
A\cdot\operatorname{adj}(A)=\operatorname{adj}(A)\cdot A = \det(A)I.
$$ If $A$ is singular, we have that $$\det(A)=0,$$ and hence $$A\cdot\operatorname{adj}(A)=O.$$ Since $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is invertible, this leads to $A=O$ and $\operatorname{adj}(A)=O$, establishing contradiction.

Comment: Great one. I have used this, but not on the right track. +1.

Comment: You mean $\det(A\operatorname{adj}(A))=0$, don’t you?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I used $\det(A)=0\Rightarrow A\cdot\operatorname{adj}(A) = \det(A)I = 0.$

Comment: How did you arrive contradiction?

Comment: Since $\operatorname{adj}(A) =0 $ is certainly not invertible.

Comment: If A=0 and adj A=0? Its vague

Comment: I mean if A (adj A)=0 then A is 0 and adj A is 0?

Comment: It flows like this: $A$ singular and $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ non-singular. $\Rightarrow \det(A) = 0 \Rightarrow A\cdot\operatorname{adj}(A) = \det(A)I = 0I = 0 \Rightarrow A=0 \Rightarrow \operatorname{adj}(A)=0 \Rightarrow\text{contradiction.}$ What part of the argument you don't understand? If we have $A\cdot\operatorname{adj}(A) =0$, then multiply the inverse $B$ of $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ on the right.

Comment: You mean if A is 0 then adj A is 0?

Comment: Yes, it is by definition. All the entries of $A$ is zero hence cofactors are zero, thus the transpose of cofactor matrix is $0$.

Comment: Got it thanks!.

Answer (score 2):

There exist $B$ such that $BA^{*}=A^{*}B=I$. Take ad joints to get $AB^{*}=B^{*}A=I$ hence $B^{*}$ is the inverse of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is singular, let $A\in \mathrm M_n$. Then $\mathrm {rank}\,A \leqslant n-1$. If $\mathrm {rank}\, A \leqslant n-2$, then every set of $n-1$ column vectors are linearly dependent, and the determinant of each  $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ submatrix of $A$ is $0$,  hence the cofactor matrix [or, the adjoint] is $0$, contradiction. If $\mathrm {rank}\, A = n-1$, then expand $\det A$ along any row, we have
$$
0 =\det A = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{j, k}A_{j,k}, 
$$
where $A_{j,k}$ is the cofactor of $a_{j,k}$. Then for $\mathrm {adj}\, A = {[A_{k,j }]_{j,k}}$, the row vectors are linearly dependent, hence $\mathrm {adj}\,A$ is singular, contradiction.

Conclusion: $A$ must be nonsingular.